# Why is it that when I click the button containing the Up function, the item.newStock number is always one behind? (React)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am making a small e-commerce site and am currently working on a shopping cart. the idea is that every time I press the button containing the Up function, the array should change and then print on the screen via item.newStock. However the first time I press the button it does nothing and the second time it adds one. But when I console.log the number is one higher than what is printed via item.newStock.

Any ideas why that is happening?

```
const Table = () => {
  return (
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table m-4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cake</th>
            <th scope="col">QTY</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {array.map((item) => {
            if (item.newStock > 0) {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{item.title}</th>
                    <td>{item.newStock}</td>
                    <td>${item.price}</td>
                    <div class="changeQTY">
                      <h5>QTY</h5>
                      <button class="up" onClick={Up}>
                        +
                      </button>
                      <button class="down">
                        <span class="minus">-</span>
                      </button>
                      <button>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            }
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button>Confirm Purchase</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
function Up() {
  setBuyQTY(parseInt(buyQTY) + 1);
  setArray((state) =>
    state.map((x) =>
      x.id === id
        ? {
            ...x,
            newStock: parseInt(buyQTY),
          }
        : x,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [`setState` is asynchronous](https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/) and `buyQTY` will not have updated when you get to that `setArray`.

Honestly, I don't see the point in `buyQTY` if each product should have its own quantity, so just get rid of it and do

```
setArray((state) =>
    state.map((x) =>
      x.id === id
        ? {
            ...x,
            newStock: x.newStock + 1,
          }
        : x,
    ),
  );
```